# rhc setup problems : An SSH connection could not be established / Authentication failed | how rhc commands work out

Tags: installation, setuptools

I had created an app review-seasonalholidays.rhcloud.com previously and I setup everything (SSH client tools), and this application was functioning very well, actually i developed the application and created  the war file and pushed it into git. As I deployed a war file named as 'review.war', I was forced to type the URL like review-seasonalholidays.rhcloud.com/review to view the home page. And when I searched that I must name the war file as 'ROOT.war', and committing on git is permanent so that i decided to delete the entire application and recreate the application on openshift along with the gears, and I removed the .ssh and .openshift folders from my home directory (Win 7), and I run the 'rhc setup' command again this time it showed me a message that: 
[An SSH connection could not be established to review-seasonalholidays.rhcloud.com. Your SSH configuration may not be correct, or the application may not be responding. Authentication failed for user 542407f25973ca35e4000080@review-seasonalholidays.rhcloud.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)].

And through putty also the connection is not established. I deleted the application again, uninstalled all ssh client tools, and recreated the application, re-installed the tools again executed the command 'rhc setup', this time also it showed the same error message.

So what i am trying to understand is "may be openshift storing my pc machine details so that it can allow one time installation/configuration", as when i run any 'rhc' command it is directly getting my application details (ofcource it may using .openshift/express.conf details), but i want my problem has to be resolved, as i need to make this application go live.

Comment: the actual problem I found is I deleted the domain 'seasonalholidays' also, I must not have deleted the domain, so that whenever i delete and create the application using this domain, there might be a mapping that is preventing the 'Authentication' to this domain. So now I want to use this domain again so how can I do this?.

Comment: Another doubt is : when I push a war file named as 'ROOT.war' and access to my app url that is 'review-seasonalholidays.rhcloud.com', it didn't lead me to my application home page. And I needed to upload review.war file and access the url as 'review-seasonalholidays.rhcloud.com/review/', what wrong I did?

Answer (score 0):

because you are rapidly deleting and re-creating the application with the same name, it will take awhile for the dns to update and point to the correct gear.  Give it a few hours and see if it starts working correctly after you create the application.

Comment: ..! Thanks for your response..! And I can wait for 1/2 days, but will I get the domain 'seasonalholidays' back? (It may be a stupid question but I am new to openshift..!)